# Should I water my indoor plant with warmer water during winter?

Tags: houseplants, watering, plant-care, avocado, overwintering

At the moment where I live the ambient temperature ranges from -5 to 5°C (23 to 41°F) and will get colder.

I have an indoor plant and I noticed that after I water it, the pot and the soil remain quite cold, well below what the ambient temperature of the room the plant is in.

The plant in question is an Avocado plant / tree, only about 50cm high and with many big leaves.  As the plant prefers a warmer climate I keep it in a warmer room during winter and it is on the window sill above the radiator.

However after watering, the plant pot and soil get, and remain very cold which cannot be good for the roots.  I had the idea to water it with slightly warmer than lukewarm water to help keep the pot and soil stay at ambient room temperature.  Will this be good or bad for the plant or will it not make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the temperature of the water, but I would not use warm water, eventually I would keep the cold water in a recipient, so that it would warm up a little bit.

But indoor plants on winter (usually) requires a lot less water: they do not get much sun, so we keep also more dry, so simulate a rest season.  So you will use a lot less water, and such water should not be enough to cold down the soil in the pot.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that as the water out of the tap is normally very cold about just letting it sit in the watering can for an hour or two to warm up a bit before watering the plant.